# what is the best usage Redis session for spring boot with external tomcat container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, redis

Folks.

I am using spring boot framework with tomcat containers, and because of several reasons for maintaining this service, I try to share sessions with Redis. Usually, I used spring-session-data-redis which is recommended by following the guide.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-session

but, I have a question about session-sharing with Redis by using spring-session-data-redis. If I need to set and use multiple server clusters to reduce traffic stress (with load balancer), should I set also a Tomcat configuration to use Redis session? or is spring-session-data-redis enough to session-sharing for multiple server clusters?

if someone visited the wrong sub-path in the specific domain (for example somewheredomain.com/not_spring_project/some_path), I guess the spring session is not working to share session. if this guy visited A-tomcat server with the correct path and went to another tomcat server with the wrong-path, maybe another tomcat server which the someone visited the first time can generate(or re-write) jsessionid.

is there anyone able to explain the best usuage session sharing for spring boot with an external tomcat container?

Answer (score 0):

A while i struggled to find the answer of this question. after making test-bed with multiple VMs on google cloud platform, finally I got the answer.

The answer is very simple, the session key of Spring-session is not jsession_id :P
so, developers don't need to worry The multiple tomcat servers issues new jsession_id.

just developers need to use spring-session-data with redis, then they can share session data on redis server.